# How to display adaptive card selected option as if the user typed it in?

Tags: botframework

By default when we use adaptive cards in a waterfall dialog, the bot records the selected action and process the next waterfall step - 
[how it actually looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZiUF.png)

Instead can we display the selected option in the adaptive card as if the user typed in the option like - 
[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wr70.png)

I have a requirement where we want to display it as if the user typed it in and not like the bot says "you selectd X option".

Comment: Is that Web Chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the 'data' property in your Adaptive Card.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "spacing": "medium",
        "size": "small",
        "weight": "bolder",
        "text": "",
        "wrap": true,
        "maxLines": 0
      },
      {
        "type": "Container"
      }
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Policy",
        "data": "Policy"
      },
      {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Scheduled",
        "data": "Scheduled"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You are awesome!