# Send Hero or Adaptive card & Get User Input on Welcome

Tags: botframework, user-input, send, adaptive-cards

I am developing Bot in .NET Core 3.1 C#. I want to send Hero card with 4 buttons & welcome prompt as soon as user joins /activates bot. I have tried it in  OnMembersAddedAsync

```
if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                var welcomeCard = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
                var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(welcomeCard);

                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync( response,  cancellationToken);
            }
```

This will display adaptive card where type is Action.Submit. But I am not sure how to get values of the button which customer click on. I tried it on OnMessageActivityAsync

```
 if (turnContext.Activity.Value != null)
        {
            var mainMenu = turnContext.Activity.Value;
        }
```

But values are always null.  Json for adaptive card is :

```
 {
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [   
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "spacing": "medium",
      "size": "default",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "text": "Welcome to ABC Bank !",
      "wrap": true,
      "maxLines": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "default",
      "isSubtle": true,
      "text": "Please select user type from below ....",
      "wrap": true,
      "maxLines": 0
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Consumer"
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Client"
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Merchant"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, could you share your card json please? really helps to answer this :)

Comment: I added Json for adaptive card.

Comment: If you are using this through webchat or directline, you just need to add the data property to your adaptive card. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62410129/how-to-display-adaptive-card-selected-option-as-if-the-user-typed-it-in

Comment: As I said before I need to send it as welcome before end user type anything. Once end user selects option I need to follow respective waterfall dialogs for that option. Code mentioned above is written in InitiateBot.cs & once customer choose options I need to go to ConsumerDialog.cs or any other dialog as per option selected by customer.

Comment: StevieBleeds is right tho. 

The "Action" element needs to have a data property or at least an ID. If you give your'r actions id's those will be send when the user interacts with your card.

Comment: Please accept Gags08's answer, and read my blog post to understand Adaptive Cards: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  As said in comments you need to add `data` property. This is not required. But if you want to collect which option user has provided you need to specify it. Since you don't have any other input field. This will act as an input to carry further operations.

**Note**: For any input element you need to use `id` property to identify collected input when submit action is performed.
Similarly for Submit action `data`. Make sure value in data for each action is unique.  If you want 2 buttons to perform same action (nativate to same dialog) then you can specify same value in `data`

Here is the official link which gives you an idea.
[Submit action](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Thanks Gags08 I can get user input (mainmenu) by adding data field in Json in OnMessageActivityAsync. Now I need to open respective dialog based on customer choice, i.e  on selection of consumer it should go to "ConsumerDialg" on selection of "Merchant"  it should go to "MerchantDialog"  How can I achieve this as everytime it goes to RootDialog & then respective Dialog.  Root is my main Dailog and it is expected to run only once. Else I need access User selection  i.e mainmenu in Root Dialog. I think I am missing some concept here.

Comment: Hi @Dnyati. Since this is a different topic.Can you please create a new question. So others can also get use of it.
As this requires a explanation.

Comment: Thanks I believe I sorted out this & it's working!! Thanks!!